# PHP PDO dblib parameters not bound

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have to connect to an external SQL database.
I am using the PDO dblib

The connection to the database works fine.
Once I try to use the prepare statement, the parameters are not set.

```
$dbh = new PDO(sprintf('dblib:host=%s;dbname=%s',self::DB_HOST,self::DB_NAME), self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);

$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ref = :id");
$sth->execute(array(':id' => 1172));
$result =  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

returns an empty array

Another attempt according to the documentation: ( http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php )

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ref = ?");
$sth->execute(array(1172));
$result =  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

also returns an empty array

Third attempt without parameters:

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ref = 1172");
$sth->execute();
$result =  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

does return a result

I also tried the $sth->bindParam() and $sth->bindValue() but I do not get any result.

I installed the dblib on a linux server , connecting to an external Microsoft 2008 SQL server.

Am I doing it in a wrong way ?

Comment: Does dblib support prepared queries?

Comment: It seems like it does. After searching for that I found something else. Apparently I can use the bindParam with the third parameter. $sth->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT); gives a result back. I still don't understand why passing an array to the execute() didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> input_parameters
>
> > An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the
> >     SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as **PDO::PARAM_STR**.

The last sentence could be the source of your problem: maybe in your database `1172` is not equal to `'1172'`. Check from the CLI if the result of the following query is `0`:

```
SELECT 1172 = '1172';
```

Comment: passing the third parameter PDO::PARAM_INT fixed the problem. thanks!